# How to disable console output from TestNG?

Tags: testng

How can I disable all console output when running TestNG programmatically via TestNG.run()? I've tried

```
   testNG.setUseDefaultListeners( false );
```

which does not make any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

testng.setVerbose(0).

..........